# Delete row from php array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove an element from an array?

For example:

```
$data = Array('first' , 'second' , 'third');
array_delete($data[2]);

#$data would now read Array('first', 'second')
```

Does such a built-in function exist?
Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, I would have made it shorter, but it needs at least 30 characters.
so here you go:

```php
unset($data[2]);
```

Comment: Nice speed of posting, do you training? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
unset($data[2]);
```

yes it does. unset().

Answer (score 4):

The above answers work. But here is what i got from the site listed below. I think its cool.

```
//deletes a number on index $idx in array and returns the new array  
function array_delete($idx,$array) {  
    unset($array[$idx]);  
    return (is_array($array)) ? array_values($array) : null;  
}
```

http://dev.kafol.net/2009/02/php-array-delete.html

Comment: yeah, returning the record deleted is nice... much like splice in javascript (there's an extra param which says how many items to delete)